# Realm schema version

Tags: swift3, realm

I have the error:

"Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 7."

when

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

on just one NSViewController class.

on others View Controllers is working ok.

Some help...

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Every time a change is made in data model delete realm files created by your app before running it. No need to increase schema version.

Comment: Great, thanks. How do you personally delete the realm files? I'm deleting the app from my phone before creating a new build, yet my Realm error still persists even though I think it is a migration/schema issue.

Answer (score 5):

This means the internal schema version number of the Realm file is 7, but if you're using the default Realm `Configuration` object, it will still be at 0.

This would imply your Realm file has gone through multiple migrations, and even if they're complete, you still need to reflect that in the `Configuration` object so Realm doesn't think it needs to run another migration.

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
schemaVersion: 7,
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    // Any migration logic older Realm files may need
})

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = try! Realm()
```

Please check out the section on [Migrations in the Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations) for more information on how the migration system works. :)

Comment: Hi TiM, I've been updating Realm.Configuration with every version. I have schemaVersion: 7 in my config. I have the problem creating an instance of Realm()in the viewcontroller of the main view. In other view controllers works fine.

Comment: Hmm, how are you instantiating that view controller? Are you doing it via a storyboard?